# SML: Creating Abstract Data Types

Tags: sml, ml, abstract-data-type

I'm writing a simple Abstract Data Type for fractions and
I cant even get the constructor to work, I'm just very lost on SML syntax.

```
signature fracs = sig

type fraction

exception zero_denominator

(* constructor *)
val // : int * int -> fraction

/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

that is the .sig file showing the constructor that i am implementing.
Here is what i have so far. the error i recieve is that I'm doing int*int* -> int
when i want int*int-> fraction.  I know what its saying and everything, but I just cant make it happen.

```
structure fracs :> fracs = struct

abstype fraction = frac of int * int
with

exception zero_denominator;
(**********************************)

(*constructor*)
infix 8 //;

fun num // den = if den = 0 then raise zero_denominator 

else
    num * den;

end;(*end ADT*)

end;(*end struct*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function signature, `A * B` means a tuple with two elements of types `A` and `B`. However in implementation, `A * B` means multiplication between two integers.

What you want is to make a `fraction` value from two integers:

```
fun num // den = 
    if den = 0 then raise zero_denominator else frac(num, den)
```